# Database Cursor

Tags: python, database, cursor

In Python, what is a database "cursor" most like?

1. A method within a class
2. A Python dictionary
3. A function
4. A file handle

I have searched on internet but I am not getting proper justification of this question.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [PEP 249 (Python Database API Specification)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-objects), it is an **object** which is expected to have certain attributes and methods defined. Optionally, [cursors can support an iteration protocol](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#iter).

This is though a spec, and, your database driver of choice may not follow the API specification. But, this is a more or less general answer to the rather general question.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it is *most like* a file handle.

That does not mean that it is a file handle, and a cursor is actually an object - an instance of a `Cursor` class (depending on the actual db driver in use).

The reason that it's similar to a file handle is that you can consume data from it, but (in general) you can't go back to previously consumed data. Consumption of data is therefore unidirectional. Reading from a file handle returns characters/bytes, reading from a cursor returns rows.